# What Does "shadows" refer to?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Turning toward our house on the hillside, I see movements of a
>   different kind, tall shadows stiffly pushing through the currents.

I think it refers to her brothers, mother and father. But I'm not sure. 
Could you explain it to me please?

The fuller text is here:

> The hill is paved with wild wheat. If the conifers and sagebrush are
>   soloists, the wheat field is a corps de ballet, each stem following
>   all the rest in bursts of movement, a million ballerinas bending, one
>   after the other, as great gales dent their golden heads. The shape of
>   that dent lasts only a moment, and is as close as anyone gets to
>   seeing wind. Turning toward our house on the hillside, **I see
>   movements of a different kind, tall shadows stiffly pushing through
>   the currents**. My brothers are awake, testing the weather. I imagine
>   my mother at the stove, hovering over bran pancakes. I picture my
>   father hunched by the back door, lacing his steel-toed boots and
>   threading his callused hands into welding gloves. On the highway
>   below, the school bus rolls past without stopping.

Educated by Tara Westover

Comment: What is the source of the quote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know from the description of the trees and the wheat that it is a windy day.

The sentence *following* your bolded query, mentions the brothers who are "[testing the weather](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/219175/what-does-testing-the-weather-mean-here)" (a previous question).

The **tall shadows** in the bolded sentence refers to those brothers.

The **currents** they are pushing through means the wind – since they are "testing the weather".

They do this **stiffly** perhaps because they are braced against the force of the wind, and the sentence is perhaps written like that to create a contrast with the swaying trees and rippling wheat.